# Regexing in Java for (\d{4},\d{4})

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to read a file and look only for numeric values in parenthesis. So an example of this would be:

```
(0000,0002)
(0000,0003)
(0002,0005)
```

I have created a regex that will search for this in java as shown:

```
public String matchDICOMTags = "^[(][\\d{4},][\\d{4}][)]$";
public Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(matchDICOMTags);
```

However in my method, when it comes to this line of code:

```
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(dcmObj.toString());
```

It does not continue with the code. I am starting to think it is a problem with my regex but I am not certain. Can someone tell me if my pattern is correct?

Comment: Do you want to just extract the two 4-digit numbers? If yes, there is a much easier way to do it.

Comment: @Bohemian basically I am reading a file that has metadata inbedded into it in the form of (0000,0000) (they are any combination of numbers and there are alot of em!). But they always have that distinct syntax of being surrounded by parenthesis and seperated by a single comma

Comment: So, I assume you just want to find these number pairs? And is there at most one pair per line? Every line? Only some lines?

Comment: Just been researching, are you trying to parse DICOM files, i.e. one of these?? http://medical.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part10/chapter_A.html or this?  http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/DICOM.html. Are you sure it's text, not binary, also if the EXIF variant, Java libraries already exist to extract EXIF tags...

Comment: Yes I am and I am using the dcmtoolkit to parse dicom tags. But I want to extract the tags to an array list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The \d{4} patterns for digits should not be inside [] as this causes them to be literal character matches. Also I believe the ^ and $ markers are not necessary, it works with or without them. Also , does not need to be inside a [] block.

Move them outside

```
"[(]\\d{4},\\d{4}[)]";
```

Test

```
String test = "other stuff (0000,0002) foo \n(0000,0003) bar \n(0002,0005)baz";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(](\\d{4}),(\\d{4})[)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("(%s,%s)", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)));
}
```

Output

```
(0000,0002)
(0000,0003)
(0002,0005)
```

Comment: @ryekayo And if you need capture the values as matches you can use 
[(](\\d{4}),(\\d{4})[)]

Comment: I got this: Enter DICOM File Path Name: 
C:\\IM-0001-0001.dcm
false when I plugged in your print statement.

Comment: @Adam, in the file i am looking at, it may contain hundreds of that pattern but they should not normally match numerically

Comment: @ryekayo I recommend a good regular expression's guide http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Adam I am punching in a file location so that my program can read and do pattern matching. I will update shortly

Comment: I need the parenthesis and comma as well

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to extract all the matches into an array list

Comment: Adam the C:\\IM-0001-0001.DCM is the filepath. Basically I am using a JAR file to read the DCM file and match anything it sees w the regex and add the matches to an arraylist

Comment: I think I finally understand, the input could be String test = "(0000,0002)\n(0000,0003)\n(0002,0005)"  ?

Comment: Lol no I am sorry Adam, the input is what is found from the file IM-0001-0001.dcm

Comment: Agreed it comes from file but I don't have the files you have in front of me, or know about the format you're talking about which is why need example to debug problem...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner to get a list of `String[]` pairs:

```
List<String[]> pairs = Arrays.stream(input.split("[\n\r]+"))
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll(".*\\((\\d{4},\\d{4})\\).*", "$1"))
        .filter(s -> s.length() == 9)
        .map(s -> s.split(","))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Some test code:

```
String input = "foo(0000,0002)bar\n(0003,0004) bar\nfoo(0005,0006)";
Arrays.stream(input.split("[\n\r]+"))
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll(".*\\((\\d{4},\\d{4})\\).*", "$1"))
        .filter(s -> s.length() == 9)
        .map(s -> s.split(","))
        .map(Arrays::toString)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[0000, 0002]
[0003, 0004]
[0005, 0006]
```